# razor sql driven select list trying to combine results of sql

Tags: html, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am making a module in dnn using razor. I am trying to make a drop down list that selects all user email addresses based on a profile property. but every time I make a field it shows up with a field for each email address...  so im looking for how to make a drop down list, that would say something like All users Committee Volunteer ect. and then have it pull the emails from there....  here is the basic select stamtent I am using in razor:

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("SiteSqlServer");
var ListDataItems = db.Query("SELECT U.email FROM dbo.USERS AS U LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT up.UserID, MAX(CASE WHEN ppd.PropertyName = 'Committee' THEN up.PropertyValue ELSE '' END) AS Committee FROM dbo.UserProfile AS up INNER JOIN dbo.ProfilePropertyDefinition AS ppd ON up.PropertyDefinitionID = ppd.PropertyDefinitionID and ppd.PortalID = 0 Group By up.UserID) as upd on U.UserID = upd.UserID Where upd.Committee >''");}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>ForEach</title>
        </head>
        <body>       
          @foreach(var ListItem in ListDataItems){<P>@ListItem.email,</P>}        
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, do you need a dropdownlist having all the SQL results in it?

Comment: I want to have a drop down list that has the results of the sql in it... Ex Select email as All users from users and so on

Comment: I got you, please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes your code to display SQL Results in Dropdownlist -

```
@{
    // Here instead of List<String>, get your SQL List of items.
    List<string> model = new List<string>();
    model.Add("California");
    model.Add("Virginia");
    <p>Select an Item : @Html.DropDownList("MyDropdownlist", new SelectList(model), "--Choose State--")</p>
}
```

Output:

[image]